# php curl is not working while debug proxy server like fiddler is working

Tags: php, curl, openssl, fiddler

I am trying to scrape from a site which is behind cloudflare.
My code is::

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://targetsite');     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"current_bid_status":true}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [                  
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',  
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($data)                    
]);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo ($ch);
```

The response header was 403, and the response body was `error code: 1020`
It looks like cloudflare is blocking the request.
But when i add fiddler proxy:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
```

It works nicely!

What can be the possible reason here? Is it something related with ssl certificate?

_

Comment: You're asking about behaviour controlled by something completely outside of your code. How are the other involved parts set up? Do you get the same using `curl` or `wget` on the commandline?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt
Yes, that is completely outside of my code but fiddler is just a debug tool. It lets the request pass through it. Nothing more. 
So here is my confusion, if this is an issue with ca certificate or not

Comment: Your question already contains the answer: Cloudflare blocks PHP - most likely based on TLS handshake fingerprinting. Fiddler is .Net based and thus has a different TLS fingerprint.